# Kiel traduki “job advertisement” al Esperanto?

Tags: translation

Do, kiel? Mi ne povis trovi tradukon en PIV, nek en ReVo, kaj la gugla tradukilo (kompreneble, mi tute ne kredas ĝin) aludas pri:

> anonco de laborposteno

Ĉu tio estas ĝusta, kaj se ne — kion mi uzu?

Answer (score 3):

La vorto, kiun vi serĉas, estas *dunganonco*. Guglu "dunganonco" kaj vi trovos kelkajn ekzemplojn:

- Bv. trovi dunganoncon de EEU por la posteno de direktoro plenumenda ekde majo 2005.
- Kvankam komisiano Verheugen rekonis la diskriminacian naturon de la dunganonco, kiu postulis denaskan scipovon de la angla ...
- Mi skribis al la menciita adreso por ekscii, ĉu ne indus krei veran afiŝeton kun dunganonco.